# What does "typename =" mean in the template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, generic-programming

I have seen this expression in page 189 of the book "Effective Modern C++":

```
    template<typename T,
             typename = typename std::enable_if<condition>::type>
    explicit Person(T&& n);
```

I am just wondering what does the part "`typename =`" mean. It certainly looks like a default argument for a template parameter. But don't you need something like "`typename some_name = ...`" in a default argument? There is no name for the second template argument, and I don't see the second template argument being used in this case.

P.S. When I search on google (or any other search engine) for an answer, the equal sign is always discarded, and this just makes finding an answer almost impossible...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That's an optional template parameter with no name and a default value.
It's used to apply the `enable_if` condition; it will create a compiler error if the condition is not met.

You can use exactly the same syntax for normal method arguments.

Comment: To clarify this phrase: `it will create a compiler error if the condition is not met`: Is it fair to say this triggers SFINAE ("Substitution Failure Is Not An Error") and the constructor is not defined?  (I am a bit new to SFINAE.)